# keep rows with latest date for matching ids. Remove all rows with old dates for matching ids

Tags: pandas

From data frame ignore hosts only with column:STATUS in "decommissioned".

For same hosts with status in both "decommissioned" and "active" state select rows with LAST_MODIFIED greater than others.

```
Input.csv

LAST_MODIFIED,       HOST,   STATUS
7/01/2019 10:20:00,  host1,  decommissioned
6/01/2019 02:10:02,  host1,  active
6/01/2019 02:10:02,  host1,  active
5/01/2019 02:10:02,  host1,  decommissioned
6/20/2019 10:20:00,  host2,  active
6/10/2019 01:20:02,  host3,  decommissioned
6/01/2019 02:10:00,  host3,  decommissioned

output.csv

LAST_MODIFIED,       HOST,   STATUS
7/01/2019 10:20:00,  host1,  decommissioned
6/20/2019 10:20:00,  host2,  active
```

Comment: Your output date for host 2 seems wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mask using `transform` + `any` to find groups that have at least one active element. Mask then `sort` + `groupby` + `tail` to get the greatest `'LAST_MODIFIED'` row.

```
#df['LAST_MODIFIED'] = pd.to_datetime(df.LAST_MODIFIED)

m = df.STATUS.eq('active').groupby(df.HOST).transform('any')
res = df[m].sort_values('LAST_MODIFIED').groupby('HOST').tail(1)
```

#### Ouput: `res`:

```
        LAST_MODIFIED   HOST          STATUS
4 2019-06-20 10:20:00  host2          active
0 2019-07-01 10:20:00  host1  decommissioned
```

Comment: Thanks.@ALollz your answer is working as expected. Since df.STATUS is not liking leading && trialing spaces in headers,, I am removing them from entire dataframe. df=pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=' *, *', engine='python')